# How to soft delete one to many relationships in EF core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Let's say that I have a Category and Product entity with one to many relationship and when I delete Category I want to delete all products that belong to the category. And by deleting I mean setting IsDeleted flag to true since I don't want to delete it for real (which I could by specifying on delete cascade). I found out the way to set IsDeleted to true when Category is deleted however I can't figure out how to find products of that category and do the same thing for them. Any help?

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach(var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<Category>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted))
        {      
            item.State = EntityState.Modified;
            item.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I also specified query filter so that I don't get deleted items

```
    builder.Entity<Category>().Property<bool>("IsDeleted");
    builder.HasQueryFilter(c => !EF.Property<bool>(c, "IsDeleted"));
```

Comment: I think Category entity has Products named property, from where you can get a list of products that belong to that category.

Answer (score 0):

Just use on cascade delete. When you delete category also all products of that category will be marked as deleted based on navigation property. This will be done by EFCore itself. I'm using this aproach in my code to soft delete one to many relation. Then use (so your code repeated on products):

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

    foreach(var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<Category>().Where(e => e.State 
     == EntityState.Deleted))
    {      
        item.State = EntityState.Modified;
        item.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
    }

    foreach(var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<Product>().Where(e => e.State 
     == EntityState.Deleted))
    {      
        item.State = EntityState.Modified;
        item.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach but it does not work for me and I have no idea why

Comment: Same problem for me too, It seems that the Deleted entity has his state to modified instead of deleted.